# SafeHTML alternative? It doesn't seem to be available anymore

Tags: coding-style

Tried various sites. All download links point to pixel-apes.com which no longer seems in existence.

Any alternatives you guys like? I'm planning on using Markdown if that affects anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[safehtml Version 1.3.7.](http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/browser/tags/6.1/plugins/safehtml/readme.txt)